How to use a package installed via npm in a standard javascript file?
I installed this package via npm: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/zebra-browser-print-wrapper
I first did npm i zebra-browser-print-wrapper like it states.
In my normal javascript file, I added the cdn link like below:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zebra-browser-print-wrapper@0.1.4/lib/index.min.js"></script>
Before writing any code to leverage this new package, when I load the page, I get the following error in the console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at index.min.js:7:1461
which is this line within that file:
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
I do see the package is in my package.json file as follows:
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./static/css/src/input.css -o ./static/css/styles.css",
    "watch": "npx tailwindcss -i ./static/css/src/input.css -o ./static/css/styles.css --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "flowbite": "^2.4.0",
    "zebra-browser-print-wrapper": "^0.1.4". <-------------
  }
}

I'm not sure if I'm missing something basic/simple. I'm fairly new to npm.

It kinda seems like the instructions for installing the package by wrapping it in the <script> tag is if you have an HTML file and want to import zebra. Once it's in the HTML file, you can use it in other <script> wrapped bits of JavaScript throughout the page.
By installing it with npm, it should be available for you to have something like:
const ZebraBrowserPrintWrapper = require('zebra-browser-print-wrapper'); 
in a separate JS file.
Update: Sheesh, so I've looked into it a bunch and I can't seem to get it working.
I've tried to requirejs,
I changed the install statement on their site to use the module setup,
I tried to import it instead of require it,
I've tried removing the require statement because I was getting an error that it was already defined.

Glad it’s not just me then!  phew

Another update :|.
I looked into the github repo to see
https://github.com/lhilario/zebra-browser-print-wrapper/issues/4
and common RequireJS errors (https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html)
and manually pointing requirejs to the local files
`require.config({
    paths: {

        'zebra-browser-print-wrapper': '../node_modules/zebra-browser-print-wrapper/lib/index',

        'constants': '../node_modules/zebra-browser-print-wrapper/lib/constants'

    }

});`

still to no avail
